# Can make perfect voxels with Blender using an addon or tools? How?

Tags: modeling

I've tried this using the remesh modifier with cubes and looks great, but it loses the texture/coloring, and the cubes aren't perfect, the cubes aren't at same size and position on a 3d grid.

The cubes must be all the same size, and the positions be align by the cubes size.
The texture/colors and uv must be made from views(front,back,left,right,bottom,top) and pixelated interpolating colors.

Comment: Please use the [edit](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/136347/edit) link at the bottom of your question and add more information to help us understand your problem. [Add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post) that might help us understand your scene and settings. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)